# Removable labels within text box

Tags: jquery, css, textbox

I am trying to replicate the following behaviour whereby a user enters text into a text box, and on clicking out the text box, the text entered is turned into a removable label (also very similar to adding a tag in a question on SO) -

[image: Removable label]

I am able to create a watermark in a text box like so -

**CSS**

```
input.watermark {
    color: #D3D3D3; font-weight: 400;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
(document).ready(function() {

    var watermark = ''; // watermark value

    $('#myID').val(watermark).addClass('watermark');

    $('#myID').blur(function(){
        if ($(this).val().length == 0){
            $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
        }
    });

    $('#input_fname').focus(function(){
        if ($(this).val() == watermark){
            $(this).val('').removeClass('watermark');
        }
    });
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager/v3

Comment: Have you tried [**select2**](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding and removing the class in jQuery, you can work in CSS to make a separate class for the text box and change the opacity for the text box when it is being hovered over to make the label disappear and in a sense 'removed'.